# KD Tree alternative/variant for weighted data

Tags: search, data-structures, indexing, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I'm using a static [KD-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) for nearest neighbor search in 3D space.  However, the client's specifications have now changed so that I'll need a *weighted* nearest neighbor search instead.  For example, in 1D space, I have a point A with weight 5 at 0, and a point B with weight 2 at 4; the search should return A if the query point is from -5 to 5, and should return B if the query point is from 5 to 6.  In other words, the higher-weighted point takes precedence within its radius.

Google hasn't been any help - all I get is information on the [K-nearest neighbors algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).

I can simply remove points that are completely subsumed by a higher-weighted point, but this generally isn't the case (usually a lower-weighted point is only partially subsumed, like in the 1D example above).  I could use a [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) to query all points in an NxNxN cube centered on the query point and determine the one with the greatest weight, but the naive implementation of this is wasteful - I'll need to set N to the point with the maximum weight in the entire tree, even though there may not be a point with that weight within the cube, e.g. let's say the point with the maximum weight in the tree is 25, then I'll need to set N to 25 even though the point with the highest weight for any given cube probably has a much lower weight; in the 1D case, if I have a point located at 100 with weight 25 then my naive algorithm would need to set N to 25 even if I'm outside of the point's radius.

To sum up, I'm looking for a way that I can query the KD tree (or some alternative/variant) such that I can quickly determine the highest-weighted point whose radius covers the query point.

FWIW, I'm coding this in Java.

It would also be nice if I could dynamically change a point's weight without incurring too high of a cost - at present this isn't a requirement, but I'm expecting that it may be a requirement down the road.

Edit: I found a paper on a [priority range tree](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3527), but this doesn't exactly address the same problem in that it doesn't account for higher-priority points having a greater radius.

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm?

Comment: That's a machine-learning algorithm, I need an index/search algorithm

Comment: Can you create a second graph G2, create the KD-tree for G2 and query it? Weights of the edges in G2 would take into account the original distances and the vertices weights (it would take O(n^3) time to build it, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution: the [nested interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Higher_dimension), which is an implementation of a 3D interval tree.  Rather than storing points with an associated radius that I then need to query, I instead store and query the radii directly.  This has the added benefit that each dimension does not need to have the same weight (so that the radius is a rectangular box instead of a cubic box), which is not presently a project requirement but may become one in the future (the client only recently added the "weighted points" requirement, who knows what else he'll come up with).

Answer (score 4):

Use an extra dimension for the weight. A point `(x,y,z)` with weight `w` is placed at `(N-w,x,y,z)`, where `N` is the maximum weight.

Distances in 4D are defined by…

```
d((a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)) = |a - e| + d((b, c, d), (f, g, h))
```

…where the second d is whatever your 3D distance was.

To find all potential results for `(x,y,z)`, query a ball of radius `N` about `(0,x,y,z)`.